# MySQL query to get the primary key(customer_id) from a table and to compare it with the current session id(customer_id)

Tags: php, sql

i' having this error when i run this code.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pta\cc11205\booking.php on line 32

```
 $querycust = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = ".$_SESSION['customer_id']" ");
```

tq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your query, Change your query to this

```
$querycust = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = '".$_SESSION['customer_id']."' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you are lacking concatenation symbol in the string. for clarity i'll rather store the seesion in a variable, eg

```
$session_var = $_SESSION['customer_id'];
$querycust = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = $session_var");
```

consider also using `PDO` or `MySQLI` extension to prevent from `SQL Injection`.

Comment: then i got another error Undefined index: customer_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\pta\cc11205\booking.php on line 32

Answer (score 0):

escape your quotes.

```
" SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = \".$_SESSION['customer_id']\" "
```